# gnuplot : plotting data from multiple input files in a single graph

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a graph using gnuplot. I have six text files. Each text file contains two columns. The first column represents time in seconds (a floating point number). The second one is a sequence number. I want to plot the graph of time vs. sequence number in a single graph for all six files. I am using this file to do that.

```
set terminal png
set output 'akamai.png'

set xdata time
set timefmt "%S"
set xlabel "time"

set autoscale

set ylabel "highest seq number"
set format y "%s"

set title "seq number over time"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid

set style data linespoints

plot "print_1012720" using 1:2 title "Flow 1", \
plot "print_1058167" using 1:2 title "Flow 2", \
plot "print_193548"  using 1:2 title "Flow 3", \ 
plot "print_401125"  using 1:2 title "Flow 4", \
plot "print_401275"  using 1:2 title "Flow 5", \
plot "print_401276"  using 1:2 title "Flow 6"
```

Where my files are:

- `print_1012720`
- `print_1058167`
- `print_193548`
- `print_401125`
- `print_401275`
- `print_401276`

It is giving a strange error as below:

> "plot.plt", line 24: undefined variable: plot

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to plot the input data from different files in the same graph?

Comment: Be clever,
go to this topic
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946530/loop-structure-inside-gnuplot

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You're so close!

Change

```
plot "print_1012720" using 1:2 title "Flow 1", \
plot "print_1058167" using 1:2 title "Flow 2", \
plot "print_193548"  using 1:2 title "Flow 3", \ 
plot "print_401125"  using 1:2 title "Flow 4", \
plot "print_401275"  using 1:2 title "Flow 5", \
plot "print_401276"  using 1:2 title "Flow 6"
```

to

```
plot "print_1012720" using 1:2 title "Flow 1", \
     "print_1058167" using 1:2 title "Flow 2", \
     "print_193548"  using 1:2 title "Flow 3", \ 
     "print_401125"  using 1:2 title "Flow 4", \
     "print_401275"  using 1:2 title "Flow 5", \
     "print_401276"  using 1:2 title "Flow 6"
```

The error arises because gnuplot is trying to interpret the word "plot" as the filename to plot, but you haven't assigned any strings to a variable named "plot" (which is good – that would be super confusing).

Answer (score 81):

You may find that gnuplot's for loops are useful in this case, if you adjust your filenames or graph titles appropriately.

e.g.

```
filenames = "first second third fourth fifth"
plot for [file in filenames] file."dat" using 1:2 with lines
```

and

```
filename(n) = sprintf("file_%d", n)
plot for [i=1:10] filename(i) using 1:2 with lines
```

Comment: I know this is old, but thank you for adding that alternative solution.  Wasn't aware of loops in gnuplot, and they're an amazing feature.

Comment: Assuming normal filename convention (name.dat) I think this should be file.".dat". The first . concatenates the filename to "dat" but isn't included in the filename actually used in the plotting command.

Comment: How can I plot *all* the files in a directory without explicitly writing their names? (http://stackoverflow.com/q/29969393/855050)

Comment: I've added an answer to that question, @becko.

Answer (score 33):

**`replot`**

This is another way to get multiple plots at once:

main.gnuplot

```
plot file1.data
replot file2.data
```

Run:

```
gnuplot -p tmp.gnuplot
```

It does not work on PNG output, only on the interactive window. Sample output:

[image]

Test data:

```
python -c 'for i in range(10): print(f"{i} {i}")' > file1.dat
python -c 'for i in range(10): print(f"{i} {i*i}")' > file2.dat
```

The documentation is present at: http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/node150.html

Tested on gnuplot 5.4.4, Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: best answer, the first one did not work. Output was: "format must have 1-7 conversions of type double (%lf)". While the other options only allow you to do it if all the data columns are the same.