# Loop structure inside gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any way to iteratively retrieve data from multiple files and plot them on the same graph in gnuplot. Suppose I have files like data1.txt, data2.txt......data1000.txt; each having the same number of columns. Now I could write something like-

```
plot "data1.txt" using 1:2 title "Flow 1", \
     "data2.txt" using 1:2 title "Flow 2", \
      .
      .
      .
     "data1000.txt"  using 1:2 title "Flow 6"
```

But this would be really inconvenient. I was wondering whether there is a way to loop through the **plot** part in gnuplot.

Comment: Really cosy `bash` function in the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34913776/3569208)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

There sure is (in gnuplot 4.4+):

```
plot for [i=1:1000] 'data'.i.'.txt' using 1:2 title 'Flow '.i
```

The variable `i` can be interpreted as a variable or a string, so you could do something like

```
plot for [i=1:1000] 'data'.i.'.txt' using 1:($2+i) title 'Flow '.i
```

if you want to have lines offset from each other.

Type `help iteration` at the gnuplot command line for more info.

Also be sure to see @DarioP's answer about the `do for` syntax; that gives you something closer to a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks your solution "plot for [i=1:1000] 'data'.i.'.txt' using 1:2 title 'Flow '.i" worked for me.. I am using gnuplot 5.2 with C++ on Windows....

Comment: But i have another problem, I am writing a program which write K number of files on hard disk from via fream K is a global variable so, I want to plot K number of files on my graph using gnuplot I tried for[i = 1:K] but it gives error of undefined variable.
I tried outside for loop from gnuplot but that also does not work.

Comment: I wrote a function in C++ for gnuplot that works with for[i = 1:5] but when I use for for[i = 1:K] it gives error...

Comment: @MasoodUrRehman it sounds like you might be trying to use a variable from your C++ code in your gnuplot script; make sure you are printing the value of the variable K when you send commands to gnuplot. Gnuplot is saying 'undefined variable' because C++ knows what K is but gnuplot does not. If you are still stuck it might be good to post your issue as a separate C++ question.

Answer (score 95):

Take a look also to the `do { ... }` command since gnuplot 4.6 as it is very powerful:

```
do for [t=0:50] {
  outfile = sprintf('animation/bessel%03.0f.png',t)
  set output outfile
  splot u*sin(v),u*cos(v),bessel(u,t/50.0) w pm3d ls 1
}
```

http://www.gnuplotting.org/gnuplot-4-6-do/

Comment: Can I also use the iterator t to refer to an index in an array of for example file names or colors?

Comment: I've never tried but I don't see any problem with that. Eventually the other possibility is to specify the array's items (colours, names or whatever) directly in the squared brackets, as shown in `help do`.

Comment: I asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591986/loop-over-array-in-gnuplot, because it is not obvious to me, how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 11):

I have the script all.p

```
set ...
...
list=system('ls -1B *.dat')
plot for [file in list] file w l u 1:2 t file
```

Here the two last rows are literal, not heuristic. Then i run

```
$ gnuplot -p all.p
```

Change `*.dat` to the file type you have, or add file types.

Next step: Add to ~/.bashrc this line

```
alias p='gnuplot -p ~/./all.p'
```

and put your file `all.p` int your home directory and voila. You can plot all files in any directory by typing p and enter.

**EDIT** I changed the command, because it didn't work. Previously it contained `list(i)=word(system(ls -1B *.dat),i)`.

Comment: For me your code does not work. I had to write `list=system(ls -1B *.dat)` instead.

Comment: Hm, OK. I was on version 4.6 on Linux.

Comment: So i tried it again, and as you say it doesn't work. I had to use ad single quotes inside the system call for your command to work: `list=system('ls -1B *.dat')`

Comment: it doesn't work for me. with or without quotes. why?

Comment: @samira I don't know.

Answer (score 11):

Use the following if you have discrete columns to plot in a graph

```
do for [indx in "2 3 7 8"] {
  column = indx + 0
  plot ifile using 1:column ;  
}
```

Comment: Only example provided here that shows how to loop through non-consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use wildcards to plot multiple files often placed in different directories, while working from any directory. The solution i found was to create the following function in `~/.bashrc`

```
plo () {
local arg="w l"
local str="set term wxt size 900,500 title 'wild plotting'
set format y '%g'
set logs
plot"
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
        do str="$str '$1' $arg,"
        shift
done
echo "$str" | gnuplot -persist
}
```

and use it e.g. like `plo *.dat ../../dir2/*.out`, to plot all `.dat` files in the current directory and all `.out` files in a directory that happens to be a level up and is called `dir2`.

Comment: You may add `plo() { [[ $# -eq 0 ]] &&  echo "Usage plo file1 file2 ..."  || { .... } }` to avoid to call `gnuplot` without files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the alternative command:

```
gnuplot -p -e 'plot for [file in system("find . -name \\*.txt -depth 1")] file using 1:2 title file with lines'
```