# loop over array in gnuplot

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, gnuplot

<sup>This question is related to [Loop structure inside gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14946530) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17884635) there by [DarioP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140449/dariop).</sup>

gnuplot 4.6 introduced the do command. How can I use this to loop over an array of for example files and colors? What is the correct syntax?

```
colors = "red green #0000FF"
files = "file1 file2 file3"

do for [i=1:3] {
  plot files(i).".dat" lc colors(i)
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you want to have all files in a single plot, you need to use `plot for[...` (supported since version 4.4). Looping over several `plot` commands with `do for` (supported only since version 4.6) works only in `multiplot` mode.

The following two solutions both plot all data in one graph, but differ a bit in the iterations.

The first solution uses `word` to extract a word from a string directly when plotting.

```
colors = "red green #0000FF"
files = "file1 file2 file3"
plot for [i=1:words(files)] word(files, i).'.dat' lc rgb word(colors, i)
```

The second solution changes the `linetype` and then iterates directly over the word list instead of using an index.

```
colors = "red green #0000FF"
files = "file1 file2 file3"
set for [i=1:words(colors)] linetype i lc rgb word(colors, i)
plot for [file in files] file.'.dat'
```

Comment: I only just got around to test it now. I prefer your second solution, which does not require multiplot mode. It works. Beautiful solution. I did not know about "words" and "word" despite having used gnuplot for more than a decade. Thank you.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Your approach with `do for .. plot` works only in `multiplot` mode. Both my solutions use `plot for [...` and give a single plot. I refrased my anwer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I also learned that "word" and "words" are covered in the string variables demo for those that want to study that in greater detail: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/stringvar.html