# Plotting data included in script fails in loop

Tags: loops, gnuplot

I would like to plot data points included inside a script file.
This should be done multiple times (plotting to different files).
Therefore, I am using a do-for-loop.

This loop let's Gnuplot freeze on excution.
Could you please hint me to the cause?

This is my MWE:

```
reset
set autoscale

do for [index=1:1] {
plot "-" with lines ls 2 notitle
0.500 5
1.000 6
1.500 7
e
}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946530/loop-structure-inside-gnuplot.   Just a wag since I don't have v4.6 but it could be the inline data is not supported within a loop, try putting the data in a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, seems like the combination of `do for` with inline data isn't supported. It also wouldn't be very convenient, since this would require a separate data block for every iteration like in

```
set style data linespoints
plot '-' using 1:2, '-' using 1:3
1 2 3
4 5 6
e
1 2 3
4 5 6
e
```

With version 5.0 inline data blocks were introduced which allow reusing inline data:

```
$data <<EOD
1 2 3
4 5 6
EOD
do for [i=2:3] {
    plot $data using 1:i w l
    pause -1
}
```