# Gnuplot: Is there a way to set the number of ytics?

Tags: gnuplot

As the title said.

I want to control the number of ytics.

I do not want to manually set the increment of ytics.

Is there a way?

Comment: How does this question differ from your previous one: [Gnuplot how to lower the number of tics in x axis](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23152207/2604213)?

Comment: Last question's answer can not work for me this time as my data is inline rather than in a separate file. I can not use stats command.......Asked again just to see if there are better solutions or if new version (v5) has built in support already. :)

Comment: No, there have been no changes regarding these options. So basically andyras' answer with `stats` still holds. But in v5 you will be able to define inline data blocks which you can use multiple times :) See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25796694/2604213 for an example.

Comment: Perhaps the code in my answer to [How to get the distance between automatic generated gnuplot tics?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25989366/2604213) helps you to get this working.