# Script Gnuplot on windows OS

Tags: windows, bash, automation, gnuplot

I would like to automate the generation of graphs from a list of data files.

More details : 
I have a directory that contain all my data files. I need to generate a graph for each of these files (hundreds). I have a gnuplot file to generate one graph but the name of the data file is specified into the gnuplot script.

For example :

```
plot 'myfile' index 1  using 1:2 with linespoints pointtype 2 linecolor rgb "green"  title "leg"
```

I need to be able to replace  "myfile" by a variable name that can be iterated on all the files of my directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a (Windows) batch file with the following command:

```
for %%G in (*.dat) do gnuplot.exe -e "fn='%%G'" script
```

This will run gnuplot (and *script*) for every `.dat` file in the current directory.

The `-e` switch is used to [input variables via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12328603/3235496) (here the filename, surrounded by quotes in case it contains spaces).

If you want to run this command directly from the shell (as opposed to within a batch file), remove one of the % symbols from each of the two pairs.

Within the script file:

```
plot fn index 1  using 1:2 with linespoints pointtype 2 linecolor rgb "green"  title "leg"
```

If the data files have a "normalized" name (e.g. `data1.dat`, `data2.dat`...) take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947085/3235496

Answer (score 2):

In general you can iterate over many files inside gnuplot as follows:

```
set terminal pdfcairo
list = "fileA fileB fileC"

do for [file in list] {
    set output file . '.pdf'
    plot file
}
```

That kind of iterations requires at least version 4.6.0. In this example you have a fixed list of file names (these are not allowed to contain white spaces).

On Windows you could use

```
list = system('dir /b *.txt')
```

to get such a list containing all `.txt` files in the current directory. Note, that you must use `wgnuplot_pipes.exe` for this to work.

On a Unix system you could use

```
list = system('ls *.txt')
```