# Plotting curves from multiple files with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot in the same graph a series of data contained in different directories with gnuplot.

I have a collection of folders called `Ntimestep=X` (where X can be for example 100, 200, 400 and so on). Inside each of this folder I have a file `occ.dat` which contains the data I want to plot, let's say 3 columns (first x points, second and third y points).
I want my gnuplot script to automatically detect all the folders by the name `Ntimestep=X` and add the data contained in the file `Ntimestep=X/occ.dat` in my plot.

I want also the number X to appear in the legend of the plot.

Example directory structure:

```
- Ntimestep=100
  ~ occ.dat
  ~ <other files>
- Ntimestep=200
  ~ occ.dat
  ~ <other files>
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Please give a couple of example folder names and filenames, and an example of your data and of your plotting commands.

Answer (score 3):

Gnuplot itself cannot create such file list, but you can call some command line tool or a second script which creates such a list, which can then be used by gnuplot.

So something like

```
list = system('ls Ntimestep=*/occ.dat')
plot for [file in list] file
```

On Windows something like `list = system('dir /b *.txt')` should work, see [Script Gnuplot on windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26356883/2604213) (I cannot test it).

To get the number in the title, using only gnuplot you can use

```
t(s) = (s2 = s[11:*], s2[0:strlen(s2)-8])
plot for [file in list] file title t(file)
```

To be more flexible regarding the string format you'll again need to use an external tool (e.g. pipe the output of `ls` through `sed`).