# Plot all files in a directory simultanously with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to do something similar to this question: [gnuplot : plotting data from multiple input files in a single graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11092608/855050).

I want to plot simultaneously *all* the files in a directory, without having to explicitly write their names. The column numbers are the same for all the files. What can I do?

Doing `plot for [file in *] file u 3:2` doesn't work.

Also, I don't want each file to have a different legend. All points from all files should be treated the same, as if they all came from a single file.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26682241/2604213

Comment: @Christoph Thanks +1, that almost solves my problem. I edited the question, though, since I don't want each file to have a distinct legend.

Comment: Which plotting style do you want, do you need a legend at all and which OS do you work on?

Comment: @Christoph I am on Ubuntu 14.04.2 64 bits. Since I have only one dataset (the data from all the files combined), I don't need a legend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
a=system('a=`tempfile`;cat *.dat > $a;echo "$a"')
plot a u 3:2
```

This uses the command line `tempfile` command to create a safe, unique, and disposable temporary file. It mashes all of the data files into this file. It then echoes the file's name so gnuplot can retrieve it. Gnuplot then plots things.

Worried about header lines? Try this:

```
a=system('a=`tempfile`;cat *.dat | grep "^\s*[0-9]" > $a;echo "$a"')
```

The regular expression `^\s*[0-9]` will match all lines which begin with any amount of whitespace followed by a number.

Comment: No need to use a temporary file, just use `plot '< cat *.dat'`.

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to Jonatan's answer, I would go with

```
FILES = system("ls -1 *.dat")
plot for [data in FILES] data u 1:2 w p pt 1 lt rgb 'black' notitle
```

or

```
plot '<(cat *.dat)' u 3:2 title 'your data'
```

The first option gives you more flexibility if you want to label each curve. For example, if you have several files with names `data_1.dat`, `data_2.dat`, etc., which will be labeled as `1`, `2`, etc., then:

```
FILES = system("ls -1 data_*.dat")
LABEL = system("ls -1 data_*.dat | sed -e 's/data_//' -e 's/.dat//'")

plot for [i=1:words(FILES)] word(FILES,i) u 3:2 title word(LABEL,i) noenhanced
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to be able too choose the files to plot with wildcards, so if you like that you can do as follows, though there are many ways. Create the following script.

script.sh:

```
gnuplot -p << eof
set term wxt size 1200,900 title 'plots'
set logs
set xlabel 'energy'
plot for [ file in "$@" ] file w l
eof
```

do `chmod u+x script.sh`

Run like `./script.sh dir/* *.dat`

If you need it often make an alias for it and put it in some reasonable place:) 
Cheers /J

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
gnuplot -e 'plot for [file in system("find . -depth 1 -type f -print")] file u 3:2'
```

<sup>Note: Add `-p` to keep the plot window.</sup>

Comment: use `system("find *.dat -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '\"%f\"\n'")` if the files have spaces