# plotting all the text files in a directory with gnuplot

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I need to plot all the text files I have in a directory simultaneously. I plot them individually with gnuplot and it worked fine. So my data is ok. But since there is too many of files I'm looking for a script to do it for me.

I tried to follow the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969393/plot-all-files-in-a-directory-simultanously-with-gnuplot), so typed this in the gnuplot

```
a=system('a=`tempfile`;cat *.txt > $a;echo "$a"')
plot a u 3:2
```

but I get this error:

```
         plot a u 3:2
                    ^
         warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
                     ^
         x range is invalid
```

Ady idea? 
I'm new to gnuplot, so I don't really understand what does  `plot a u 3:2`  is supposed to do.

Comment: Are your txt files on the same path as your script?

Comment: you were right, as soon as I noticed I fixed it and updated the question with the error.

Comment: I'm nt familiar with gnuplot. What does u 3:2 mean? maybe there's some mismatch with the actual data and the plot configuration.

Comment: Show us your data: `cat *.txt` (in the system). Show us `a`: `a` (in `gnuplot`). This would already (probably) disclose you a problem. `u 3:2` means plot `3rd` column against `2nd` column. You do not have such columns, and do not have a plot - easy ;)

Comment: :) `u` is the short name for `using`. (Other abbreviations, [see 4.1 here](http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html))

Comment: Thanks. I used 'plot a u 1:2' and it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u 3:2` means plot 3rd column against 2nd column.

You do not have such columns, and do not have a plot - easy.

Just misuse of `using`.

---

#### Update:
 How to plot each file with different color, and what the line `system(...)` means

Plot, modifying the solution you initially found

```
a=system('a=`tempfile`; awk "{if ((FNR==1) && (NR!=1)) {printf \"\n\n\"}; print \$0}" *.txt > $a;echo $a;')
plot a u 1:2:(column(-2)) with lines lc variable
```

#### Explanation:

`system` makes Unix system call to execute some command (string) in shell.

String is placed in single or double quotes inside parenthesis: `system('...')`.

`tempfile` is a Linux utility to create temp file.

To plot files with different colors one could use `lc variable` option `gnuplot`. It needs the data to be separated into **blocks**. We use ***two blank lines*** to separate blocks.

`awk` could process multiple files: `awk '...' list_of_files...`, I use double quotes `awk "<command>"` to distinguish between these quotes and quotes from `system` command.

```
awk "{if ((FNR==1) && (NR!=1)) {printf \"\n\n\"}; print \$0}" *.txt
```

If we have the first line of some file `(FNR==1)`, but not the first file (total number of records processed `NR!=1`), we should print two blank lines `printf \"\n\n\"` to indent new block for `gnuplot`.

print \$0 prints full line (`$0`). Double quote \" before newline symbol `\n` and `$` are escaped to be not expanded by the shell - the drawback of `" "`  (even, it is enough to tell `awk`: `print`).

Example:

```
==1.txt==
1 1
2 2
3 3
==2.txt==
4 1
5 2
6 3
==3.txt==
7 0
7 2
8 4
8 2
```

Output from `awk` command (see the command above):

```
1 1
2 2
3 3


4 1
5 2
6 3


7 0
7 2
8 4
8 2
```

`plot a u 1:2:(column(-2)) with lines lc variable` makes `gnuplot` plot the 2nd column vs the 1st one, coloring each block of data with its index. Index of data block is obtained with special `gnuplot` variable: `(column(-2))`.

Comment: hanks. I used 'plot a u 1:2' and it fixed. Now I have a plot with hundreds of graphs in it. Do You know how can I make them distinguishable? probably with different colors or more resolution? I also don't know what 'a=system('a=`tempfile`;cat *.txt > $a;echo "$a"')' exactly do?

Comment: Oh, it is not for two words - I will update the answer then!