# Using two arguments in sprintf function in gnuplot

Tags: printf, gnuplot

I've been trying to graph several files on the same gnuplot graph using sprintf to read in the filenames. I can read in one argument o.k. if I write:

```
filename(n) = sprintf("oi04_saxs_%05d_ave_div_sub.dat", n)
plot for [i=1:10] filename(i) u 1:2
```

then my graph is o.k and I get all files with that argument plotted on the same graph. However I have a string of characters that changes near the end of my filename and when I try to reflect this in

```
filename(n,m) = sprintf("oi04_saxs_%05d_0001_%04s_ave_div_sub.dat",n,m)

plot for [i=1:10] filename(i,m) u 1:2
```

I get the following error message: 'undefined variable m'. I've tried removing the loop and just running

```
plot for filename(m)
```

and this results in the same error message. Help in understanding what's going wrong and how to fix it would be much appreciated :)

This is my full script:

```
unset multiplot
reset

set termoption enhanced
set encoding utf8

set term pdf size 18cm,18cm font 'Arial'

set pointsize 0.25

set output 'StoppedFlowResults.pdf'

set logscale

set xlabel '{/:Italic r} / [Q]'
set ylabel '{/:Italic Intensity}'

filename(n) = sprintf("./Result_curve-%d.txt/estimate.d", n)

myColorGradient(n) = sprintf("#%02x00%02x", 256-(n-1)*8-1, (n-1)*8)

set key off

set multiplot layout 2,1

filename(n,m) = sprintf("oi04_saxs_%05d_0001_%04s_ave_div_sub.dat",n,m);

plot for [i=1:10] filename(i,m) u 1:2 not

unset multiplot

set output
```

Comment: As the error message says: You don't define `m` anywhere before you use it with `plot for [i=1:10] filename(i,m)`.

Comment: but don't I define it when I write    filename(n,m)=sprintf("",n,m)? isn't that defining it from the list of potential filenames?

Comment: No, there you have a function definition, so the second function parameter is available as `m` inside the function body, but only there. It is a different issue when you call your `filename` function. And, now that I see it, you have two different `filename` definitions.

Comment: Ok... this is helpful; but how do I solve the problem? I've just tried running the code by changing the second definition so it only reads in one variable so:    `filename(n,m)=sprintf("", n,m)  br/ plot for [i=1:10] filename(i) u 1:2 not`

Answer (score 0):

based on `help for`, you can have nested iterations e.g.:

```
plot for [i=1:3] for [j=1:3] sin(x*i)+cos(x*j)
```

In your case you can mix this with strings (you have yet to define string possible values) with something like:

```
plot for [i=1:3] for [m in "A B C D"] filename(i,m) u 1:2 not
```

Comment: so I have to define possible string values? I was hoping to use this as a workaround to that....

Comment: Well, as @Christoph mentioned above, you have to tell gnuplot the pattern to find those files. Either you have a list of strings, either you glob in `ls` like stylle with a pattern as explained in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678584/plotting-curves-from-multiple-files-with-gnuplot)