# Gnuplot: plotting data from several subdirectories in one plot

Tags: bash, gnuplot

Suppose I have a results directory with many subdirectories, one for each experiment. In each of these subdirectories are the data files, so the whole thing looks like this:

```
results
    exp_1
        data_file.dat
        other non-relevant stuff
    exp_2
        data_file.dat
        other non-relevant stuff
    exp_3
        data_file.dat
        other non-relevant stuff
    ...
```

The question is, is there a way to plot all the data files in one plot with Gnuplot (from the results folder) in an automatic way? (Right now I only have 50 experiments, but I could easily wind up with thousands. It is impractical to specify 50 relative paths as it is!)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26678584/2604213

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I did search but I never found a question that addressed my needs. That worked, but I can't upvote yet (your answer should also have been marked as accepted on the other post). Thanks!