# How to shift values on the x axis from actual values to axis origin

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have data to plot in files structured like this:

```
(timestamp MegaBytes)
1487936469 0.003617
1487936470 0.081604
1487936471 0.244869
1487936472 0.322519
1487936473 0.242145
1487936474 0.34596
1487936475 0.385525
1487936476 0.324402
1487936477 0.154996
1487936478 0.24336
1487936479 0.38952
1487936480 0.46152
...
```

plotting with

```
using 1:2 with lines lw 3
set xlabel "seconds"; set ylabel "MB"
set format x '%.0f'
```

[image]

The plot is fine, but the x axis (time) is not nice to see: is there a gnuplot command that allows me to shift from the x range [`1487936469`,`last time stamp`] to [`0`,`last value`] so that x axis values would start from `0` instead of `1487936469`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel stupid to high five myself, but here's how I solved this:

```
gnuplot> set grid
gnuplot> set xlabel "seconds"
gnuplot> set ylabel "MB"
```

My files have .log extension: create a list of files to be logged.

```
gnuplot> list = system('ls *.log')
```

"u": using, "w l": with lines, "lw": line width

```
gnuplot> plot for [file in list] file u 1:2 w l lw 3 title file
```

After this plot, special variables have been set, check them with:

```
gnuplot> show variables all
    ...
    GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN = 1487936460.0 <- this is what I wanted
    ...
```

I will subtract `GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN` to all values in x axis: store it in a variable and replot (`$1` is the first column, the one with timestamps):

```
gnuplot> MIN=GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN
gnuplot> plot for [file in list] file u ($1-MIN):2 w l lw 3 title file
```

[image]

Much better!
Credit goes to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034891/how-do-i-make-a-plot-in-gnuplot-with-the-lowest-value-automatically-subtracted-f) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678584/plotting-curves-from-multiple-files-with-gnuplot/26682241#26682241).