# Setting a title in a loop depending on the counter

Tags: gnuplot, title

I have a for-loop like

```
 for[i=2:12] for[j in "3 6 8"] {code}
```

In my code I plot something and i'd like to put something in the title, 
such as "things and stuff value1" and value1 is calculated over i and j, for example

> value1=i*j+1/2.

How can I calculate it then, for example in the title or a label?

Comment: I think you missed the language tag, can you hit [edit] and add that, please?

Comment: Also, please read the description for `tag:title`. As a new user, you probably want to take the [Friendly Introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks for the answer...i don't know what you mean with language tag though

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop structure inside gnuplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946530/loop-structure-inside-gnuplot)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `for` loop inside a `plot` command:

```
plot for [ii=2:12] for [jj in "3 6 8"] x*ii*jj title 'x*'.ii."*".jj
```