# manipulating bash variables within gnuplot

Tags: bash, scope, gnuplot

I'm trying to create a live animation with gnu plot using the reread command.

my main program outputs a series of data files like

```
 0.0000000.dat
 0.1000000.dat 
 10.500000.dat
```

etc. and I want the script to serially plot each of these files and stop when it runs out of file (pause on the last one).

This is what I have so far.  Get_File_Name is a bash function which formats the file names properly.

```
source ~/Source_Me/*.sh

shopt -s expand_aliases

### Process input parameters
if [ "$1"  ];
then
        Time=$1
else
        echo "No start time detected, starting at 0.0"
        Time=0.0
fi

if [ "$2"  ];
then
        Increment=$2
else
        echo "No time increment specified. choosing 0.1" 
        Increment=0.1
fi

if [ "$3" ];
then
        FrameDelay=$3
else
        echo "No frame delay time specified, choosing 0.25 s"
        FrameDelay=0.35
fi



FileName=$(Get_File_Name $Time orbs)
        # Do this from command line
        #Do the plotting
gnuplot << EOF
t = $Time       
print t
        set pm3d map
        splot "$(Get_File_Name $Time orbs)" u 1:2:8


        pause 1 
       ### Increment the time somehow
       ### reread conditionally upon the existence of the next file
EOF
```

I know that you can call a bash function within gnu plot using

```
system "<command>"
```

but this creates a new environment which can't manipulate existing variables.
I can't figure out how to manipulate the bash variables within the gnu plot block.

```
    gnuplot << EOF
     EOF
```

How can I increment the time and filename variable within the gnuplot block?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your question implies the `gnuplot` is within a `bash` loop yet it doesn't appear to be.

Comment: If I put the `gnuplot` inside a `bash` loop then the plot window would close between each iteration.  This is unacceptably slow.  If I used the native `gnuplot` command `reread` then the same plot window would remain open and the displayed data would change.

As I understand it `reread` would loop back to the `gnuplot << EOF` every time it is hit.   If I put `reread` in a conditional statement as indicated in the `###`, this would effectively give me a while loop inside `gnuplot`

Comment: to clarify, my issue is that I don't know how to implement `Time+= $Increment` inside the `gnuplot <<EOF` `EOF` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this relevant question:

[Loop structure inside gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946530/loop-structure-inside-gnuplot)

which gave me a workable solution.  Rather than updating the file name, it is sufficient to build a list of file names using

`list = system('ls -1B *orbs.dat | sort -n ')`

I think using `system()` rather than `system ""` allows me to save the output of the bash line as a `gnuplot` variable.