# Gnuplot: Plot several in files in different folders

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have several files which have the same name, `data`, in different folders named `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, I want to plot columns 1 and 2 of all files in the different folders at once. In other words, from the root where `folder1..3` are located I don't want to use:

> p 'folder1/data' u 1:2, 'folder1/data' u 1:3

and

> p folder2/data' u 1:2, 'folder2/data' u 1:3

and again for folder3 and the 28 other folders, I have in the real case.
Are there a `for` command or some related command in Gnuplot that I can, at once, plot all `data` files from the different folders, preferably in different windows?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `help for` to learn about loops in gnuplot. It seems like

```
plot for [i=1:3] "folder".i."/data" u 1:2, for [i=1:3] "folder".i."/data" u 1:3
```

might be all you need.

Whether or not you can automatically create plots for different files in different windows probably depends on your chosen output terminal. For `x11` you could probably do something like

```
do for [i=1:3] {
    set term x11 i
    plot "folder".i."/data" u 1:2, "" u 1:3
}
```

(not tested).

Answer (score 0):

`gnuplot` can handle as many files as you like in a single command.

Simply issue your `plot` command separating each file and column specification with a comma (as you have begun doing above)

```
plot \
"folder1/data" using 1:2,
"folder1/data" using 1:3,
"folder2/data" using 1:2,
"folder2/data" using 1:3,
"folder3/data" using 1:2,
"folder3/data" using 1:3
```

Generally each `plot` command will produce output in a separate window (it depends on how `gnuplot` is called -- whether in a separate process or not).

When called from a shell script, you can spawn separate subshells to produce output in separate windows, or within a C-program, you can `fork` separate processes for the same purpose.

You can also use `multiplot`, see [Multiplot – placing graphs next to each other « Gnuplotting](http://www.gnuplotting.org/multiplot-placing-graphs-next-to-each-other/comment-page-1/)

You may also find parts of you question answered here [gnuplot : plotting data from multiple input files in a single graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092608/gnuplot-plotting-data-from-multiple-input-files-in-a-single-graph)

---

**edit Based on Comment**

OK, now that I understand you want to automate building a plot file from a list of directories named `folderXX` (where `XX` can be anything) below the current directory, and in each folder there will be a file named `data` where you want to plot the first against each of the 2nd and 3rd columns, then you can build a temporary plot file (say `tmp.plt`) by looping over the list of `folderXX` (you can adjust the globbing to your needs) and outputting the plot commands as you go using simple redirection.

For example, something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

## truncate tmp.plt and set line style
echo -e "set style data lines\nplot \\" > tmp.plt

cnt=0   ## flag for adding ',' line ending

## loop over each file
for i in folder*/data; do
    if ((cnt == 0)); then       ## check flag (skips first iteration)
        cnt=1                   ## set flag to write ending comma
    else
        printf ",\n" >> tmp.plt             ## write comma
    fi
    printf "\"$i\" using 1:2,\n" >> tmp.plt ## write using 1:2
    printf "\"$i\" using 1:3" >> tmp.plt    ## write using 1:3 (no ending)
done
echo "" >> tmp.plt              ## write final newline
```

(**note:** `echo` and `printf` are alternated to get the desired escape behavior for the line-continuations)

When run within a directory containing `folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4`, each containing a `data` file, e.g.

```
$ tree
.
├── folder1
│   └── data
├── folder2
│   └── data
├── folder3
│   └── data
├── folder4
│   └── data
```

it will result in a `tmp.plt` plotfile that can then be called with `gnuplot -p tmp.plt`, e.g.

```
$ cat tmp.plt
set style data lines
plot \
"folder1/data" using 1:2,
"folder1/data" using 1:3,
"folder2/data" using 1:2,
"folder2/data" using 1:3,
"folder3/data" using 1:2,
"folder3/data" using 1:3,
"folder4/data" using 1:2,
"folder4/data" using 1:3
```

This should be closer to what you were looking for based on your comment.

Comment: I would like to avoid writing that 56 times (28 folders x 2 columns each), that's why I was wondering if some sort of loop, as the name of the files are the same, and the directories names are numbered.

Comment: Oh -- now it is clear... you can just build the gnuplot command dynamically or you can write your plot command to a file and then execute that. Hold on and I'll look at putting together an example. **How are your folders ordered?** and **Do all folders under a directory contain `data` files?**