# GNUPLOT: Follow command to the next line?

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following script called `tmp.plt` for gnuplot:

```
plot \
"n300_50int/ini-ene.his" using 1:2, \ 
"n500_100int/ini-ene.his" using 1:2, \ 
"n500_1ooint_0.65e3/ini-ene.his" using 1:2, \ 
"n500_50int/ini-ene.his" using 1:2
```

But it gives me the error

```
samuel@samuel-P5Wx6:~/Documents/Fisica/19-20/Radiactividad/Prácticas/Practicas-MontCarlo/PET/Simulaciones$ gnuplot -p tmp.plt 

plot "n300_50int/ini-ene.his" using 1:2, \ 
                                         ^
"tmp.plt", line 2: invalid character \
```

I've created this script with the following .sh (edited from the one in [Gnuplot: Plot several in files in different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201280/gnuplot-plot-several-in-files-in-different-folders) ) :

```
#!/bin/bash

## truncate tmp.plt and set line style
echo -e "plot \\" > tmp.plt

cnt=0   ## flag for adding ', \' line ending

## loop over each file
for i in */ini-ene.his; do
    if ((cnt == 0)); then       
        cnt=1                   
    else
        printf ", \\ \n" >> tmp.plt             
    fi
    printf "\"$i\" using 1:2" >> tmp.plt 
done
echo "" >> tmp.plt
```

And I don't understand why it doesn't work when the next `test.plt` file does

```
f(x)=x
g(x)=2*x
plot \
f(x) , \
g(x)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is erroring because of the backslash (`\`) in the `tmp.plt` file. The reason is that `\` needs to be the last character on the line as per the `gnuplot` instructions. There is a space after your `\` in the nonworking example. If you add a space after the `\` in the working example it will error, too. As shown here:

```
plot f(x) , \ 
            ^
"test.plt" line 4: invalid character \
```

So try:
 `printf ",\\\n" >> tmp.plt` (or just `printf ",\n" >> tmp.plt`)

instead of:
 `printf ", \\ \n" >> tmp.plt`

Comment: It was the space, indeed. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Check out the instructions here on how to accept an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers